# How to save multiple R objects to a file with other data?

Tags: r, file, ggplot2, logging, save

This is for a tool I am building, so my solution can't be adhoc. I would like to save a ggplot object to a log file, which contains a lot of other information. Then I would use many of these log files to make a combined plot of all the ggplots. I've tried just saving the images as .pngs and then combining them in R but the quality decreases significantly when combining them from image files. Any ideas?

I don't want to save them to indiviual .Rdata files because I'd like all the information to be contained within the log file. Is my only option to save the dataframe used to construct the ggplot and then reconstruct it later?

Comment: The format of a `ggplot2` grob is rather unique to R, and it is a rather complex (and large) object even for small plots. While it may be feasible to encode the grob into something you can store in a logfile (`jsonlite`), I suspect there might be internal refs in the object that render that part difficult. I suggest, lacking more context, that your use of the term "logfile" might be a stretch, since they are often (not always) ascii or at least non-binary. How about a log-directory, each file is an entry (and an `.rda` file).

Comment: Thanks for the information! I had not considered that ggplot2 objects could be quite large. I think you make a great point. It actually might make more sense to just write all of my information into a .rda file and use that as my log file! Thank you so much

Comment: As always, it depends, but if you have lots of layers, lots of individual points, etc, then it can add up. A simple scatterplot of `mtcars` is merely 13KiB, so not gargantuan, but while one thing might be "cheap", many things add up to "not as cheap".

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure the reason for embedding in a log file, but you have two options here with saving r objects.

Option1.  Save several memory objects at once.

```
save(ggplot1object, dataframe2, dataframe3, file = "location.filename.Rdata")
```

Then you can

```
load("location.filename.RData")
```

and all 3 objects will be loaded into memory.

Option 2. Create a List and save the list.

```
save(list(ggplot1object, dataframe2, dataframe3), "location.filename.Rdata")
```

Then you can

```
load("location.filename.Rdata")
```

and the single list item with the 3 different pieces will be loaded into the environment.  These can be `ggplot` output items like `p1`, `p2`, etc... that represent different plot objects.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would thumbs up but this is my first post :(. The reason for embedding these all within the log files would be to contain all the information within one file so when an aggregate tool searches recursively for all the log files, it only has to worry about one type of file. I think that is the cleanest solution from a software engineering perspective. I hope that makes sense. I may be forced to either do this or write the data as is into a log file then compress the file.

Comment: Side note: iteratively adding to a `.rda` file might eventually slow down, as the amount of data increases. If you know you are just appending data and not going to use everything from the existing `.rda` file, you might see better performance by writing each grob to a new `.rda` file and only `load`ing them when you intend to combine them. Just a thought.

Comment: I had to specify the save path with `"file=mydata.Rdata"`